# iOS How to check ABRecordRef ABAddressBook, ABPerson has WhatsApp enabled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, abaddressbook, whatsapp, abrecordref

Hi I use the following code and pass the abid and I am able to send a message to users who have WhatsApp installed but how do I know before I send a message that the user has WhatsApp setup? I don't want to enable the option if it will not work for a specific user.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?abid=%d&text=%@", abid, @""]]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't.

`ABAdressBook` is not associated with WhatsApp, and the `openURL` thing only launches WhatsApp if installed (didn't check the target contacts have WhatsApp account or not. WhatsApp does not provide API to check whether the number has registered an account or not.

Comment: Hmm ok thank you. How about how to make a call programmatically using WhatsApp does it provide API for that yet or just SMS?

Comment: WhatsApp has very limited API, through custom URL scheme. See [this](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013)

Comment: Thank you scamps, I accepted Raptor answer because its what I needed to know. I wanted to know if there was a way to tell if the target account has a registered account with whatsApp or not. Think of it like this as an example if a user in my contacts has a Facebook or a Twitter account, there would be a property associated with it and I was hoping there was something like this for WhatsApp.